# Flutter Error - Undefined name used as annotation

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

Learning flutter, and getting this error when I add @Override on top of the function. Not sure where to import it from. In Android Studio, I used to hit Alt+Enter to import, but I am using Visual Studio Code, not sure what to do in this case.

Undefined name @Override used as annotation.
Try defining the name or importing it from another library.

> Compiler message: lib/main.dart:17:4: Error: Getter not found:
>   'Override'.   @Override    ^^^^^^^^ lib/main.dart:17:4: Error: This
>   can't be used as metadata; metadata should be a reference to a
>   compile-time constant variable, or a call to a constant constructor.
>   @Override

```
  @Override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    ...
  }
```

Comment: It should be `@override` with a lowercase "o".

Comment: Yes! Thank you, can't believe i missed that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your spelling if you get this error message, it could be a spelling error, like in my case.

If the spelling is correct, try to import it from another library.